# Create a dataframe with multiplied records

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have three lists as below and would like to create a dataframe:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
list3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Is there any possibility to create a dataframe of size list1*list2*list3 (315 rows) with values:

```
list1   list2   list3
1       1       1
1       1       2
1       1       3
1       1       4
1       1       5
1       1       6
1       1       7
1       2       1
1       2       2
and so on.
```

I am stuck with logic here. If any one could help it will be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which returns cartesian product :

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

x = list(product(list1,list2,list3))

df = pd.DataFrame(x)

print(df)
```